# How to write conditionals in R

Tags: r

I have data that has the height, weight, sex and age.

I want to create a column that has BMI status that indicates (1)overweight, (0)healthy weight (there are no children in this data set that are underweight).

However, this needs to be based on age.

I have two categories for age:

- 8, 9, 10 11,= children ~ 0
- 12, 13, 14, 15 = teens ~ 1

The BMI status category needs to be:

- age (0):
  overweight status with a BMI of 21 or higher,
  healthy weight with a BMI lower than 21
- age (1):
  overweight status with a BMI of 23 or higher,
  healthy weight with a BMI lower than 23

```
bmi_child <- data %>%
  select(famid, age, sex, ethnicity, height1_child, weight2_child)

 
bmi_child$BMI <- (bmi_child$weight2_child *703)/(bmi_child$height1_child)^2

bmi_child <- bmi_child %>%
  mutate(age_category = case_when(
    age %in% c("7", "8", "9", "10", "11" ) ~ 0,
    age %in% c("12", "13", "14", "15") ~ 1)
    )

bmi_child <- bmi_child %>%
  mutate(BMI_status = case_when(
     BMI > 21 ~ 1,
     BMI < 21 ~ 0))
```

I've been messing around with If statements but am unable to get workable code to make the bmi status column as a condition of age_category

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide your data firstly. To copy the result of  `dput(data)` to your question.

Comment: You missed a `TRUE ~ xxx` within `case_when` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Comment: Simpler: `mutate(age_category = age > 11)`.

Comment: And: `mutate(BMI_status = if_else(age_category, BMI > 21, BMI > 23)`. I've left both these as logical. You can make them numeric if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```r
bmi_child <- bmi_child %>% 
               mutate(
                 age_category = age > 11,
                 bmi_status   = if_else(age_category, BMI >= 23, BMI >= 21)
               )
```